# How to match fit_tranform of the imputed dataset with the original dataset while handling missing data in an ML model?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imputation

When trying to fill up missing values using KNNImputer algorithm using the following line of code:

```
pd.DataFrame(knn_imputer.fit_transform(data),
                        index=data.index,
                        columns=data.columns)
```

I am receiving error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\myname\Desktop\Project\PythonTool\calculator\database-analyzer\database_analyzer.py", line 384, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\myname\Desktop\Project\PythonTool\calculator\database-analyzer\database_analyzer.py", line 232, in main
    train_data_engineered = missingvalue_handler(train_data_engineered)
  File "c:\Users\myname\Desktop\Project\PythonTool\calculator\database-analyzer\utilities_module.py", line 1268, in missingvalue_handler
    return pd.DataFrame(knn_imputer.fit_transform(new_data),
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 695, in __init__
    mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 351, in ndarray_to_mgr    
    _check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 422, in _check_values_indices_shape_match
    raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (196, 1032), indices imply (196, 1033)
```

I know there reason for this is that imputer actually imputes one column completely bringing them down from 1033 to 1032. How can I fix the issue while not knowing which column has been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I did not need to know the exact column name. I made the following change to make sure data.shape[1] and len(data.columns) match while making a pandas dataframe from the imputed dataset.

```
pd.DataFrame(knn_imputer.fit_transform(data),
                        index=data.index,
                        columns=data.columns)
```

to

```
pd.DataFrame(knn_imputer.fit_transform(data),
                        index=data.index,
                        columns=data.dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns)
```

Comment: My workaround works for training dataset but not for test dataset. Does anyone know why?